# Use Git amend with merge conflicts

Tags: git

My story is that I started with branch `feature/bar`, made changes and commit.

Then I checkout from this branch to `feature/foo`, made some changes, and commit.

Then I return to `feature/bar`, made more changes and commit.

Now, when I checkout to `feature/foo` and merge `feature/bar`, I have conflicts.

But I don't want to create another commit message in `feature/foo`. I want to use `git amend`, so my change log will stay clean.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "change log will stay clean"?

Comment: This is an open source library and I have ChangeLog based on the commit messages.

Comment: @Bazinga. Then use rebase instead of merge. Or just fix your conflicts.

Comment: @Bazinga In addition to the workflow changes in my answer, you could make your commit log to change log process a little smarter than to blindly include every commit. For example, it could include *only* merge commits since each merge is now closing a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My story is that I started with branch feature/bar, made changes and commit. Then I checkout from this branch to feature/foo, made some changes, and commit. Then I return to feature/bar, made more changes and commit.*

Git history is a graph, so let's graph this out. Your repository looks like this.

```
A - B - E - F [feature/bar]
     \
      C - D [feature/foo]
```

`foo` and `bar` have *diverged* meaning there are commits in the parent branch since the child branched. This is normal.

> *Now, when I checkout to feature/foo and merge feature/bar, I have conflicts. But I don't want to create another commit message in feature/foo.*

Instead of updating a branch with merge, update it with rebase. This simplifies the process by pretending your branch was written on top of the current `foo` all along.

`git merge feature/bar` gives you this. And if you do it enough times history gets messy.

```
A - B - E - F [feature/bar]
     \       \
      C - D - E [feature/foo]
```

`git rebase feature/bar` gets you this...

```
A - B - E - F [feature/bar]
             \
              C1 - D1 [feature/foo]
```

Git replays each commit in `feature/foo` on top of the current tip of `feature/bar`. So it looks like `feature/foo` was developed on the lastest `feature/bar`. There's no unnecessary merge commit.

Any conflicts are handled on the commit where they happen. So if you have a change in `C` that conflicts, Git will stop, allow you to rewrite the commit, and continue.

Note that these are new commits with new commit IDs. If you'd previously pushed `feature/foo` you'll have to push it with a `git push --force`.

---

When you're done with the branch and are ready to merge back, use `git merge --no-ff feature/foo` to ensure there is a merge commit.

```
A - B - E - F -------- G [feature/bar]
             \       /
              C1 - D1 [feature/foo]
```

You want this merge commit to keep a record of which commits were grouped together as a single feature. You can use the commit message to record information about the branch, like a link to an issue tracker. When you `git branch -d feature/foo` branch, that feature bubble is still there to help future code archeologists.

```
A - B - E - F -------- G [feature/bar]
             \       /
              C1 - D1
```

And because you updated your branch with rebase, despite the branch in history, your real git history and linear history are the same. `git log` will output the changes in the expected linear order G, D1, C1, F, E, B, A making history easy to follow.